# On a macOS M1 Computer, is it possible to use Xcode and the simulator using rosetta and run a project with libraries configured for Intel only?

Tags: xcode, ios-simulator, apple-m1, rosetta-2

I have a iOS project that I am slowly porting to use XCFrameworks, but I would need to run it for a while like it used to run on my intel Mac. Both Xcode and the simulator have the "Open using rosetta" option, but I still cannot compile the project as it is to run on simulator, archive works ok as expected. Thanks for your attention and any help.

Answer (score 0):

You can prepend `arch -x86_64` when running Xcode from terminal. This will run Xcode under rosetta:

```bash
arch -x86_64 /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/MacOS/Xcode
```